# Inserting using clause location in Sybase IQ

Tags: sybase

I'm using Sybase IQ 16 and I'm trying to insert data from a Sybase ASE 15.7
I defined an ODBC dsn for Sybase ASE and the connection test is positive,
the name of the DSN is EMS_SERVER_ems, this dsn is defined on database ems,
I created the server within Sybase IQ using the command create server:

```
create server EMS_SERVER
CLASS 'aseodbc'
using 'DRIVER=Adaptive Server Enterprise;dsn=EMS_SERVER_ems';
```

I also created the external login

```
create externlogin DBA to EMS_SERVER
REMOTE LOGIN DBA identified by sql
```

but when I'm trying the command :

```
insert MyFirstIqTable
location 'EMS_SERVER.ems' {select * from my_table}
```

then I get the error :

> Could not execute statement.
>   CtLibrary Error: 44, Severity: 0, Origin: 1, Layer: 4

Error Message:

> ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
>   OS Error: 0, OS Message:
>   (hqmlib\hqm_con.cxx 199)
>   SQLCODE=-1003002, ODBC 3 State="HY000"

Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: The error message seems to imply that the server cannot be reached.  Can you verify that the server be reachable?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, this was because my external login was wrongly defined.
It's working like a charm !